# Simple wpf mvvm asynchronous example

Tags: wpf, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have very simple restful service that handles all data requests for my wpf application. I know that the best practice indicates getting those long running requests off of the UI thread.

I'm using .NET 4.5 so I can utilize some of the newer tools, async/await, TPL. I've created some sample projects and I understand the concept. Problem that I just can't seem to get a grasp on is handling the async stuff in the viewmodel. In my sample projects, the async work always happens in the codebehind - easy enough. Once its abstracted to the viewmodel - I lose it.

I have a very simple generic class that handles all of my rest web reqeusts. Ideally I want the async work to happen there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I recommend for `async` MVVM projects:

- Treat your VM like it has UI affinity.
- Async methods are commonly used for initialization and commands.
- Properties only represent the *current state*. If you find yourself trying to implement an "asynchronous property", re-evaluate your design.

With that said, there are some techniques that you may find helpful (all of these are links to my blog or my AsyncEx library).

I have a blog post on [async and constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html); the "asynchronous initialization" technique (which is compatible with IoC) is the one I recommend for VMs.

I also have a blog post on [async and properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html); there are a couple of approaches including async lazy initialization (for shared resources) and updating data-bound properties. Both of these blog posts are part of an [async OOP series](http://blog.stephencleary.com/search/label/async%20oop), but those two in particular have useful information for VMs.

Both async initialization and async property loading can use a helper type I wrote called [`NotifyTaskCompletion`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion), which essentially just observes a task and provides some data-bindable properties for that task.

For async commands (`ICommand`), you could start out with the [`SimpleAsyncCommand`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Nito.AsyncEx.Mvvm%20%28NET45,%20Win8,%20SL4,%20WP75%29/SimpleAsyncCommand.cs), which is like an `async` `DelegateCommand`. A more advanced type is the [`AsyncCommand`](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Nito.AsyncEx.Mvvm%20%28NET45,%20Win8,%20SL4,%20WP75%29/AsyncCommand.cs), which supports cancellation, progress reporting, and has a default implementation of `CanExecuteChanged` returning `false` as long as the command is already executing.

Note that `SimpleAsyncCommand` and `AsyncCommand` are not yet part of AsyncEx, so you'll have to copy/paste the source into your own project to make use of them.